# How to make a script being called inside another script in a ssh command?

Tags: shell-script, subshell

I have a ssh calling a script in a server, named `/opt/scripts/script1.sh`.

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@ip /opt/scripts/script1.sh
```

(I know sshpass is not secure but there's a reason for that in this context)

This script does a bunch of stuff then calls another script, doing `bash /opt/scripts/script2.sh`.

If I interactively ssh into this machine, and run `/opt/scripts/script1.sh`, `/opt/scripts/script2.sh` is called. But if I do

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@ip /opt/scripts/script1.sh
```

`/opt/scripts/script2.sh` is not called. I don't have an error (even doing `set -x`), nothing. I don't know why it works in one way but not in another. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: You mention that `script1.sh` "does a bunch of stuff" before starting `script2.sh`; do you still see the problem if you remove all that, so that `script1.sh` only contains the line `bash script2.sh`?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the same script? What does `set -x` say it's doing when it calls `bash ...script2`?

Comment: Write a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It helps you finding the problem.